# Let $~v(x, y)~$ be the solution of $~\frac{^2}{^2}+\frac{^2}{^2}=0~$ on $~ℝ^2~$ , then which of the following is/are true?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

**Problem:** Let the function $~v(x, y)~$ be the solution of $~\frac{^2}{^2}+\frac{^2}{^2}=0~$ on $~ℝ^2~$ and $~v = x~$ on the unit circle. Then at the origin
$(a)~~ v~ $attains maximum and minimum on the boundary of the circle.
$(b)~~ v~ $does not attain maximum and minimum on the boundary of the circle.
$(c)~~ v~ $is equal to zero.
$(d)~~ v~ $tends to infinity.

**My approach:** From the [Maximum-Minimum Principle](http://web.iitd.ac.in/%7Evvksrini/Oldhomepage/Fund-laplace.pdf) $($if $u$ is a harmonic function on a bounded domain $Ω$ in $ℝ^n$, then $u$ attains its maximum and minimum value on the boundary of $Ω)$, it is clear that **option** $\bf (a)$ is true and hence **option** $\bf (b)$ is not.
Now it is given that $~v = x~$ on the unit circle, so form here how to verify the last two options ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$v(x,y)-x$ is also harmonic and it is $0$ on the boundary. Hence, by MMP,  $v(x,y)-x=0$ for all $x,y$ in the unit disk. So c) is true and d) is false.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. But I have one doubt. Upto "$~v-x=0~$ for all $~x,~y~$ in the unit disk", it is okay for me. But from here how $~v=0~$ is true ? Is it because the value here asked at origin ?

Comment: @nmasanta Yes. (c) says $v$ is $0$ at the  origin. ( a)-d) are all about values at the origin).

Comment: Okay, thank you again @Kavi Rama Murthy